# Reload or Refresh Activity from OnClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-activity

In my "ArticleActivity" (where the user reads the article), I have a list of "related articles".  When a user clicks one, it should reload or refresh the ArticleActivity to show the article they clicked on instead of the one they just read.

I found many many answers online and have tried roughly 492 of them...  I CAN get it to start a DIFFERENT activity, but I can't get it to restart the current one.

My latest attempt:

```
    //RELATED ARTICLE CLICK
    relatedArticleClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("MYLOG", "related article clicked " + v.getId());
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ArticleActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("id", v.getId());
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }   
    };
```

**Update:**

Could have it to do with the ArticleActivity having this: `android:launchMode="singleTask"` ?  I need it there, but also need to be able to reload the activity with a new article.

If I change `ArticleActivity.class` to `MainActivity.class` and leave all the rest of the code exactly the same, it DOES go to the MainActivity.

Comment: I am not sure but I think no need to finish the activity before starting the intent...And also it would be better if you could have explain more what really happens instead of starting the activity.

Comment: Is it really necessary to relaunch the activity? In most cases you should be able to refactor your code so that the logic that happens during the initial launch of the activity can be called directly from your OnClickListener. This would be much more efficient that a full round trip with an intent.

Comment: @Dave  Try `Intent myIntent = new Intent(ArticleActivity.this, ArticleActivity.class);`

Comment: @user1132647 - I'm sure you're right - and once I get this working and have time to revisit, I will certainly try that.

Comment: @Deepzz - tried - still nothing. :(

Answer (score 1):

replace these lines

```
finish();
startActivity(myIntent);
```

with these

```
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: then remove finish() line.i fill refresh your activity but will not finish it.

Comment: @Dave : have you try it by using onNewIntent?

Comment: Still does nothing.  If I change it to MainActivity, though (instead of ArticleActivity), then it does go back to the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your update, and further understanding your question.  The behavior is related to your `singleTask` designation.  Under `singleTask`, if the activity already exists, it is not recreated, but instead its `onNewIntent()` method is invoked for you to handle the new intent.   See [Activity.launchmode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for more info.

Do you really need `singleTask`? Because removing it should also cause your problem to go away.  It will also allow your read articles to be in the back stack, so when your user is done with one article and presses the back key it will take them back to the first article.

Comment: This sounds great - but when I try it, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is showing as an error.  "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: cut and paste error, see above, but looking at your edit, I think I misunderstood your question.  You mean that you never get the 2nd article at all?  I was thinking you did not want to launch a second copy of your intent.

Comment: I tried both with the `Intent.FLAG...` and also `addFlags()` instead of `setFlags()`, but no luck. Correct, when I click it NOTHING happens (except I get my Log showing that the click happened).

Comment: Yeah, that solution was not going to work, I thought you were having a different problem.  Re-reading your edit, singleTask is causing your issue.  See edited answer above -- basically you need to implement `onNewIntent` to handle the refresh, or carefully consider the need for `singleTask`.